# Replace comma into dot using uigetfile

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to replace comma to dot from txt files in Matlab but I'm not getting. Follow below my code:

```
[nome,caminho]=uigetfile({'*.pal';'*.sjc'},'Selecione Arquivos para Palmas ou SJCampos');
newfile= [caminho nome];
fid=fopen(newfile,'rt')

data_iono=textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%f%f%s%s',-1,'Delimiter','\t','HeaderLines' ,3,'treatAsEmpty',{'-','R','F','N','Y'});
fclose(fid);
```

Can anyone help me?

Grateful!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file you're importing? Can you also give an example of the result you're getting and what you'd like instead?

Comment: Have you tried `strrep(str, ',', '.')` on the imported file?

Comment: Are *.dat and *.txt files. When I use the uigetfile command, I choose the file and it imports the data and I store in the fid variable (e.g: UT=0,12), so I need to convert to UT=0.12.Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jommy, I tried to use this command but I didn't get. See how I did:[nome,caminho]=uigetfile({'*.pal';'*.sjc'},'Selecione Arquivos para Palmas ou SJCampos');
newfile= [caminho nome];
newfile=strrep(newfile, ',', '.');
fid=fopen(newfile,'w');%Open the data file
fwrite(fid, newfile, 'char');

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which column you have commas in, but lets say it's column 4 for example.

```
[nome,caminho]=uigetfile({'*.pal';'*.sjc'},'Selecione Arquivos para Palmas ou SJCampos');
newfile= [caminho nome];
fid=fopen(newfile,'rt')

data_iono=textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%s%f%s%s',-1,'Delimiter','\t','HeaderLines' ,3,'treatAsEmpty',{'-','R','F','N','Y'});
fclose(fid);

data_iono{4} = str2double(strrep(data_iono{4}, ',', '.'));
```

What is happening is that we're importing the column containing commas as a string, replacing the commas in that column with periods and then converting the column to numbers.

Comment: Hi sclarke81! I tried use this command but it didn't work. See the message: Cell elements must be character arrays.Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you didn't update the textscan command. You can see that I changed the fourth `%f` to `%s` to import the fourth column as strings. There's a limit to how much I can help if you can't provide an example file.

Comment: How I can send an example of *.txt file for you?

Comment: You could add a few lines of a file  to your question or upload the file to one of the free file sharing services. Adding it to the question is the easiest in my opinion.